# Can TCP/UDP reverse proxies output data or respond?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

in this case using a NGINX reverse proxy.

For example:

If there is a reverse proxy between a client and a game server where the client connects to the reverse proxy then the reverse proxy connects to the game server would the game server respond back to the client with world data through the reverse proxy, or would the game server respond directly back to the client?

Hypothetical question for a real project to help defend again DoS attacks. Does a game server even send data back to the client?

```
client > reverse proxy > game server
client < reverse proxy < game server
```

or

```
client > reverse proxy > game server
client < exposed ip < game server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any 2 way communication (like a game), the server does send data to the client.

Almost all reverse proxies sit in front of the server (and act to protect the server), and handle all incoming and outgoing as per your first option.

The second scenario you present is achievable (google "[lvs Virtual Server via Direct Routing](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-DRouting.html)"), but appears to have fallen out of favour, is not a best practice, and, I would argue, is not reverse proxying, because the proxy does not have the opportunity to modify packets on the way back, which breaks HTTPS -> HTTP translation and other things.